# Why my Angular app is not setting background correctly when 2 or more components inside?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have an app that contains 4 components inside it:

```
<div [@routerTransition] class="position-relative overflow-hidden pt-3 m-md-3">
  <div class="mx-auto mb-5 pb-1 container">
    <app-set-vehicle-details id="step1" (step1Finished)="enableStep2($event)" (busy)="setBusy($event)"></app-set-vehicle-details>
    <app-product-selection id="step2" *ngIf="step2Enabled"></app-product-selection>
    <app-product-details id="step3" *ngIf="step3Enabled"></app-product-details>
    <app-customer-details id="step4" *ngIf="step4Enabled"></app-customer-details>
   </div>
 </div>
```

My view is supposed to look like this:

[image]

That corresponds to the `app-set-vehicle-details` component. Note the grey background there.
But when the second component is added, the background turns white:

[image]

But don't understand why this background is changing like that. Some css attached:

```
.theme-main [_nghost-etm-c5] {
   background-color: #F0F0F7 !important;
   color: #4D4F5C !important;
}
```

[image]

This is a screen capture of the main container:

[image]

I find no reason why the white part is appearing. The only thing that happens is that **the second component appears dynamically, after an action.** I'm not sure if that's the responsible of that height reprint?

Thanks for any help in advance!

To clarify a little bit:

- Styles are being retrieved from a custom library, called `styles.scss`
- This is the style applied to the body:

So `h-100` from Bootstrap, what produces:

[image]

But still not working... Any ideas?

Comment: Does your component have a special background in its css?

Comment: It is kind of unclear where the background-color is being set. If it's inside of your components, each component will have to set its own background. It would be better if one of your container div's sets the background, or even the `body`

Comment: No, the only background color there is the one you see. A themed one. That's why it's confusing! Not unclear btw...

Comment: Yes it is unclear. It is not clear where your background-color is set. It could be in your `styles.css`, in any of the components, or even from an external library. Iam suspecting the same as @JB17 suggests in his answer, but it wouldn't be nesscessary to guess with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I suggest setting the background color for `.pb-1` class in the main component CSS file.
Every Angular Element would be affected by common CSS (like bootstrap library) and its own CSS which reads from the CSS file of the component. The latter is specific to that component and wouldn't affect other components CSS even if they have shared class names.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the height of your body? The body doesn't update it's height when components are added so the height of your component is limited to the height of the body. To avoid that, set the min-height of the body & html in your global css file to 100% like so:

```
body, html {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I just edited my post. My height is set by Bootstrap using `h-100`, so my height is set to 100% !important, and even that, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

set background color on the **body** tag in styles.css

```css
body {
background-color: grey !important; /*Add the color you want to set */
}
```

you can also do this for the main div using some class